# AS3 Write to File

Tags: actionscript-3, api, file, actionscript

The following code only reads files rather than writing to them. I'm using Flash Player not Air and the code must save the data to an external website so FileReference and FileStream won't work.

```
var Update:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://freememegames.com/wp-content/uploads/highscore.txt");
var Score:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
var Load:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

Update.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
Score.Name = "Jack";
Score.Value = "100";
Update.data = Score;
Load.load(Update);

Load.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, Complete);

function Complete(e:Event):void {
    scores.text = String(e.target.data);    
}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, `FileReference` **does** allow you to upload and download files to a remote server. Please correct me?

Comment: The user has to browse to the location when selecting a file and the file can only be saved on the client's PC.

Comment: So, the file can only be saved on clients PC or on an external website? You are contradicting yourself.

Comment: What? Where? Please look up what FileReference does to fully understand what I'm saying and also before you provide incorrect help. I want this to run in the background without the user having to browser to my website (which is impossible anyway) and I want it to save it to my website while FileReference only saves it on the client's PC. My first reply "The user has to browse to the location when selecting a file and the file can only be saved on the client's PC." is saying what FileReference does not what I want to do. I thought that was obvious since it was a reply to your comment about FR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to send this data to PHP, and then have PHP write it into your text file. Just so you know though, what you're trying to do is prone to hacking, and you'll want to introduce server-side security to thwart people manipulating scores.

Comment: I think you are mistaken - if the file can only be saved on client side (see comments to the question), then no server side solution is required. It can all be done on client side, using Actionscript. Wouldn't you agree?

Comment: No you misunderstood, please re-read the question, his answer was correct as you can *clearly* see by the tick I gave him. "And the code must save the data to an external website."